# Fit a good Lorentzian in mathematica

Tags: fitting

Good morning everyone, 
regarding my research "high resolution laser spectroscopy" I would like to fit the data obtained from the experiment with a Lorentzian curve using Mathematica, so as to calculate the value of FWHM (full width at half maximum). 
To do this I have started to transcribe the data into "data", as you can see in the picture:

```
data = {{4.82, -3.92}, {4.84, -4.16}, {4.86, -3.52}, {4.88, -1.2}, \
{4.9, -0.8}, {4.92, -0.56}, {4.94, -0.48}, {4.96, -0.4}, {4.98, \
-0.4}, {5, -0.48}, {5.02, -0.48}, {5.04, -0.4}, {5.06, -0.48}, {5.08, \
-0.56}, {5.1, -0.72}, {5.12, -1.12}, {5.14, -3.84}, {5.16, -4.16}, \
{5.18, -4.16}, {5.2, -3.76}, {5.22, -3.6}}


ListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

I then plotted it and the result is as follows:

[image: plot of data]

What I would have to do now is just to fix it with a Lorentzian function of the shape:

$$W(x)=\frac{A}{(x-x_0)^2+B}+y_0$$

So what I thought was to write a code like this:

```
model = a/(((b - f)/c)^2 + d);
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model, {{a, 82.17435}, {b, 4.126155}, {c, 0.000283}, {d, 1.}}, f, 
   MaxIterations -> 500];
result["BestFitParameters"]
fitplot1 = 
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[result[f], {f, 4.124, 4.133}, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

The problem is that I get a lot of errors and I don't see anything ...
Can any of you give me advice on how to solve this problem?
Thank you very much and have a nice day

Comment: Please post actual code and data rather than images.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model` deviates from `W[x]`!

Try

```
model = a/(( b - f  )^2 + d) + c;
```

Method `NMinimize` doesn't need starting values:

```
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model }, { a , b , c , d }, f, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

Plot in the range of `data[[All,1]]`

```
Show[ ListPlot[data], Plot[result[f], {f, 4.82, 5.22}, PlotRange -> Full]]
```

[image]

The FWHM (full width at half maximum) is given by:

```
max = NMaximize[result[t], t][[1]] (*0.0106332*)
min=NMinimize[result[t], t][[1]] (*-9.90218*)
minmax = data[[All, 1]] // MinMax
fwhm = t /. NSolve[{result[t] == (max  + min) /2, 4 < t < 6}, t] //Differences // First
(* 0.463044 *)
```

Comment: This is just what I needed, thank you very much.
do you have any idea how to calculate the FWHM for this curve? 
Because I find a lot for Gaussian curves, but not for Lorentzian curves.

Comment: @Albano, have you seen formula 5 from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html) already?

Comment: @AlbanoTabacchi No idea, what's the meaning of FWHM?

Comment: @AlbanoTabacchi  I got it, see my modified answer

Comment: Fantastic, the only problem is that I don't understand what t is in your code, because now it gives me an avalanche of NonlinearModeFit errors.

Comment: Actually, the second piece of code is redundant. `FWHM=2Sqrt[d]`

Comment: `t` is the argument of your fit-function `result` , you called it `f`

Comment: @yarchik  Restricting ` a>0,d>0` your result is ok I think

Comment: Perfect, I understand. 
The last thing is that I don't get the result of FWHM = 0.463044, but I get f, because there is an error "Part : Part specification (-19.825)[1] is no longer than depth of object." and “NSolve : NSolve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and  numericizing the result", so I don't know if I'm wrong or if there's something I'm not seeing.

Comment: Change `max[[1]]`to `max` in the last codeline. I modified the answer

Comment: OK, now I don't get any errors but I get f and not a value

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you tried. I checked my code and it evaluates!